# PHP if a time is after and before specified time

Tags: php, if-statement, time, intervals

I'm trying to get time interval after 12AM until 21PM.
but I don't know how to do it and confused how to put it in the right statement.

well, I need a conditional statement like this:
can someone help me?

```
$date = '2016-23-05 13:00:00';

if($date > 12:00:00 and $date < 21:00:00){  
//some functions
}
else{ 
//some functions
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If(date("His", strtotime($date)) > 120000 && date("His", strtotime($date)) < 210000)
```

Comment: `h` will give you 1 not 13. so here your answer is wrong.

Comment: This won't work. See the format of the date : `2016-23-05`

Comment: True.. its capital H for 24 h time. Thanks. Why would it not work @Thamilan? Have you tried it?

Comment: I'll try it and see how the result

Comment: @HenrikusAnthony sorry I made a smal misstake. Will edit now

Comment: @Thamilan see here, it works. Date just strips out what you don't want. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc99d482be78dc0d6fe6eb131e65f9e369eb2237

Comment: @Andreas Remember when I said it. You edited your answer later. you just added `$date` without `strtotime`

Comment: @Thamilan yes I added strtotime(), I fotgott it but that still does not make `2016-05-23` the problem.

Comment: Final call.. Read the question and my comment carefully.. it is `2016-23-05` and not `2016-05-23`

Comment: @Thamilan ahhh... :-D I see. Why on earth would you mix american with european date writing? I see now what you mean